# Prince2 course in 3 days?

Tags: certification, prince2, 6-sigma

I've been looking to get myself certified for Prince2. I already have a PMP, but was wondering if I should do Six Sigma or Prince2. A friend of mine recommended this company called "[Firebrand Training](http://www.firebrandtraining.co.uk)", who claim that they certify you in [Prince2](http://www.firebrandtraining.co.uk/courses/management/prince2.asp) in just 3 days! What do you reckon? Too good to be true? Will it be a "brain dump" or can it be done? They do guarantee that we pass the exam, but I just wanted someone else's opinion if they've been on a course with them.

Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 6):

The 3 day period is typical of what I've seen for PRINCE2 Foundation training. Most providers guarantee a pass for this, though many in the fine print are clear it may take more than one try. The Practitioner certification (which is really the one that counts IMHO) usually takes another couple of days. Pass rate for this I think is similar to that for PMP, i.e. about 70-80% of candidates will typically pass.

I did my PRINCE2 prior to getting my PMP. My training was online through Advantage Learning (www.advantagelearning.co.uk), which worked well with my schedule and was about one third the price of in-class training. There are any number of providers for this. My overall effort was probably about 60 hours over three months, the vast majority of that running through practice exams. But I passed first time on both exams so I figure an ounce of prevention was worth a pound of cure....

If you have PMP you should do fine, though some of the nomenclature is different so you may have to unlearn a couple of things.

Comment: Prince2 foundation is indeed 3 days

Comment: My Prince 2 course lasted 3 days for foundation plus 2 days for practitioner, with pre-reading and evening work on top. In total I probably spent 70 hours in total (including the course) over 3 weeks, resulting in a good pass. I had lots of prior experience as a project manager - just no formal qualifications - and a bit of prior exposure to Prince 2, and probably could have managed a pass with a lot less effort.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that guarantees you certification in an area where you have no experience in only 3-5 days can only be a "brain dump". They'll teach you 'to the test' and the tricks to pass, but it's highly doubtful that you will remember much afterwards, nor be able to properly function in that arena.

I don't know Firebrand, but since you have your PMP - did you do a "boot camp"? If so, how did it go, and how much did you retain? If not, why not? That should answer your questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

Very late reply from my side but it might help other people who see this question. I did a 3 day course with Firebrand. It was foundation and practitioner combined. The classes were very intense ~12 hours a day so there also was an evening program where we needed to study. By the way: during those 3 days we slept in the same building as were the training was. So basically you were full time studying.

We started with 16 people. After the 2nd day 14/16 were foundation certified.
At the 3rd day the 2/16 did a 2nd attempt for the foundation exam and 14/16 did an attempt to pass the practitioner exam. Only 2/14 passed the exam and for one of them it already was his 2nd a try.

Indeed they guarentee you pass; if not you can do the 2nd exam attempt for free. (the exam is free but they do charge other costs). I was very lucky to passed both exams for the first time. (but i just barely made it).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to take a 3 day course and pass the PRINCE2 Foundation Exam and yes the above comments of a brain dump  (PPT Slide Dump) are correct.
This is why less than 5% of people who have a PRINCE2 Cert ever use as don't know how. They just want to pass the exam and don't care about learning PRINCE2. What a Waste :-(

My suggestion: Classroom Training
If your company pays for a classroom course, then take it.  But do about 6-8 hours of homework and you will get a lot more from the course.
1) The PRINCE2 Timeline video (20 mins): (Search "PRINCE2 Timeline" on Youtube)
    - This video offers a simple high-level introduction to a PRINCE2 Project 
    - This is the best introduction to PRINCE2

2) PRINCE2 Process Model video (60 mins): (Search "PRINCE2 Pre-Course" on Youtube)
   - Also available in Book, Audio & Q&A formats (80 Q&A)
   - This is similar to the above Timeline video but more detailed

3) Running a PRINCE2 Project:  http://bit.do/P2Trello 
- These video will show you how to use PRINCE2 to run a simple project 
- This give you a more practical approach to learning PRINCE2

My suggestion: Online Training 
- See www.prince2(.)center - List of online PRINCE2 Foundation Courses
- Choose a course that offers more than just PPT slides with a voice over